# What are struct “wrapper types”?

Tags: swift, struct, wrapper

In the [Swift.org migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) under the SDK section reference is made to *struct “wrapper types”*, I have a number of questions related to them.

> In Swift 3, many of Foundation’s “stringly-typed” APIs have been
>   changed to use struct “wrapper types”, such as the new
>   Notification.Name type. Since, it’s common for notification names and
>   other string constants to be declared globally or as static members,
>   the best way to take advantage of these new types is usually to
>   construct the wrapper at the point of declaration:

What are these, are they a wrapper function? [As described by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) or are they an implementation of the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

What are the benefits of using a *struct “wrapper type”*?

Comment: Instead of multiple long constants, e.g. `UITextFieldDidChangeNotification` you will get nice structured constants `TextField.Notification.DidChange`.